# Samba Share is mounted and shows indexing enabled, but why doesn't work?

Tags: spotlight, finder-tag, smb, indexing

I am running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 (17G65).

I enabled indexing on samba share by using `sudo mdutil -i on` command. The result:

```
$ sudo mdutil -s /Volumes/e\$/
/Volumes/e$:
    Indexing enabled.
```

I did find the indexing cache location: `/var/db/Spotlight-V100/Volumes/smb%3A%2F%2Fadministrator@ip%2Fe$/` and `/private/var/db/Spotlight-V100/Volumes/smb%3A%2F%2Fadministrator@ip%2Fe$/`.

But after three hours, I still can not find anything from the samba share via *Spotlight* and `tag` `mdfind` commands.

For example:

```
[/Volumes/e$]$ tag -a test test

# after three hours ......... 

[/Volumes/e$]$ tag -f test              # nothing returns
[/Volumes/e$]$ mdfind tag:test          # nothing returns
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answers this question, I posted what I found so far.

(1) *Spotlight* and command line tools `tag`, `mdfind` won't work on samba network drive.

(2) To search *filename* and *tag*, `Finder` app works. `Finder` --> open the samba network drive folder --> In search bar, type *filename* or `tag:tagname`, it works very well.

Comment: As for `mdfind` not working on sambas shares: yes and no. see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449782/how-can-mdfind-onlyin-find-stuff-that-mdfind-global-search-doesnt